# NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node in TensorFlow for custom loss function on large dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, loss-function

Following is my code for the custom loss function

```
def cost(self, Y, logits):
        loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(
            tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=tf.cast(Y, tf.float32), logits=tf.cast(logits, tf.float32)))
        return loss
```

I'm running this on MNIST dataset. However, I got the following error.

```
File "C:\Users\system_name\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gen_nn_ops.py", line 11838, in sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits                                                                                                                                                   
    _six.raise_from(_core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)                                                                                         
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from                                                                                                                       
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Could not find valid device for node.                                                                   
Node:{{node SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}                                                                                                              
All kernels registered for op SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits :                                                                                            
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tlabels in [DT_INT32]                                                                                                         
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tlabels in [DT_INT64]                                                                                                         
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tlabels in [DT_INT32]                                                                                                        
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]; Tlabels in [DT_INT64]                                                                                                        
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tlabels in [DT_INT32]                                                                                                          
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tlabels in [DT_INT64]                                                                                                          
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tlabels in [DT_INT32]                                                                                                         
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]; Tlabels in [DT_INT64]                                                                                                         
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tlabels in [DT_INT32]                                                                                                          
  device='GPU'; T in [DT_HALF]; Tlabels in [DT_INT64]                                                                                                          
 [Op:SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits]                                                                                                                      
[Finished in 27.01s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: are you training with `fit()` ? As far as I understand - loss functions should have two arguments in this case

Comment: I'm using subclassing. So have written my own custom ```fit()``` .

Comment: do you mean custom loop ? Or you overrided `fit()` ?

Comment: I'm using custom loop

Comment: why are you using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` ? Labels should be integer in this case. You are casting them to float

Comment: I read somewhere that It helped them solve this problem. So I used it. But you are right, that labels should be integers.

Comment: Anyway. error remains same in both cases.